# How do you reference back to a parent folder in html?

Tags: html, macos

I'm having trouble referencing back to parent folders using html. Here is a picture of my folder:

[image: folder pic]

The below code is index.html:

```
<html>
        <title>HTML Experiments</title>
        <h1>This is a website that I made</h1>
        <ul>
            
            <li>Here is another file: <a href="InsideTheRootFile1.html">another file</a></li>
            <li>Here is an extra file: <a href="extras 1/insideextras.html">extras</a></li>
            
        </ul>
</html>
```

Here is insideextras.html:

```
<html>
        <h1>it worked!</h1>
        <p>here you can go back to index: <a href=".../index.html">index</a></p>
</html>
```

Index.html works OK and I can access insideextras.html from there, but when I try to go back to index.html it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got an extra dot.

Just fix

`<p>here you can go back to index: <a href=".../index.html">index</a></p>`

to

`<p>here you can go back to index: <a href="../index.html">index</a></p>`

Answer (score 0):

First, remove all spaces in folder's and file's names. make their names as one word or use `-` or `_` to connect words. anyway, don't leave any spaces in the names. for example your folder name will be **extra-1**

**then** use one of these ways according to your folder or file location:

1-

```
<img src="picture.jpg">     The "picture.jpg" file is located in the same folder as the current page.
```

2-

```
<img src="images/picture.jpg">  The "picture.jpg" file is located in the images folder in the current folder.
```

3-

```
<img src="/images/picture.jpg">     The "picture.jpg" file is located in the images folder at the root of the current web.
```

4-

```
<img src="../picture.jpg">  The "picture.jpg" file is located in the folder one level up from the current folder
```